# Order of where clause evaluation

Tags: mysql, select

If I have a MySQL table which has content from the last 3 months I actually do the following:

```
SELECT SQL_BUFFER_RESULT SQL_CACHE count(id) cnt
FROM `mDelivered` 
where _campaign = 2
  and `session` = '0082b570177d2cee48702a21c7b2484ca4c9f24f'
  and timeCreated > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
group by `_campaign`, `session`
```

Now I think it first checks all elements where `_campaign=2`, is that right? Then it checks `where session = ...` and then it checks `where _timeCreated > ...`.

How can I make the select faster?
Is it better to reduce the size by changing the order of the element like this:

```
SELECT SQL_BUFFER_RESULT SQL_CACHE count(id) cnt
FROM `mDelivered`
where  timeCreated > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
  and _campaign = 2
  and `session` = '0082b570177d2cee48702a21c7b2484ca4c9f24f'
group by `_campaign`, `session`
```

Or is it better to:

```
SELECT SQL_BUFFER_RESULT SQL_CACHE count(id) cnt
from (
  SELECT *
  FROM `mDelivered`
  where  timeCreated > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
)
WHERE _campaign = 2
  and `session` = '0082b570177d2cee48702a21c7b2484ca4c9f24f'
group by `_campaign`, `session`
```

or how should this be done to be faster?

Answer (score 2):

See this answer. No, the order you put the conditions in the `WHERE` clause doesn't matter: [In MySQL, does the order of the columns in a WHERE clause affect query performance?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1792/in-mysql-does-the-order-of-the-columns-in-a-where-clause-affect-query-performan)

If `id` is not nullable, you can replace the `count(id)` with `count(*)` and  try adding an index on `(_campaign, session, timeCreated)`.

```
ALTER TABLE mDelivered
  ADD INDEX campaign_session_timeCreated_IX        -- choose a name for the index
    (_campaign, session, timeCreated) ;
```

And you don't need the `GROUP BY` since you are already restricting the rows to fixed `_campaign` and `session` values. Try this:

```
SELECT count(*) cnt
FROM mDelivered
WHERE _campaign = 2
  AND `session` = '0082b570177d2cee48702a21c7b2484ca4c9f24f' 
  AND timeCreated > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR ;
```